# Import telscale jss7 source code in eclipse

Tags: restcomm, ss7

I have the binaries for telscale ss7 simulator but I don't have source code. Can any one guide me how to and from where I can find the source code and also brief how can I import it into Eclipse JAVAEE.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source code at https://github.com/RestComm/jss7 and use mvn eclipse:eclipse to be able to import the projects into Eclipse.

Comment: Sir thanks for your answer but according to my observation there is no telscale ss7 simulator in here it is the stack I wanted the source code for tescalse simulator not for jss7 stack.